# Suppose G be a non-abelian group and H,K be two abelian subgroups of G. Then must HK be an abelian subgroup of G?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Suppose $G$ is a non-abelian group and $H,K$ are two abelian subgroups of $G$. Then must $HK$ be an abelian subgroup of $G$?

I know an example, but I am confused. Thus I just want to check that.

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily, the first counter-example I think of is $S_3$ (the symmetric group on three elements), with $H=\langle(1,2)\rangle$ and $K=\langle(1,2,3)\rangle$.

You can check that $HK=S_3$ so is not abelian.

Comment: I thought so. Thanks a lot ...

Comment: Perhapos even better $\;H:=\langle (12)\rangle\;,\;\;K:=\langle (13)\rangle\;$ , but $\;HK\;$ is **not** even a subgroup...

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. There are even metabelian groups (non-abelian, but $G'$ abelian) which are the product of two abelian subgroups $A$ and $B$, i.e., $G=AB$.